# How to create popup menu in IE toolbar

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to develop an IE toolbar,in which i need to show a popup menu with text box and button,if any one know the way send me the answer .

I tried to find a solution but still didn't get any solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am going to downvote this question because there is no code.